# How to check if site using word press or not?

Tags: wordpress

I need to know how I can check from PHP script all information related to site using Wordpress, Example : what theme it is using, if website is a Word press website, any WP plugin it is using etc.

Please help to provide correct answer.

I already know info related to wp-admin check, any other suggestions ?

Comment: You can look in the source, for a string like `/wp-content/themes/Whatevertheme` etc. the same can be done with plugins - JS, CSS files usually suggests which plugins are being used.

Comment: You can use this, to see which CMS is being used : https://www.wappalyzer.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Builtwith](https://builtwith.com/) website which gets you the technologies used in the website, as well as usage stats for each of the technologies. Also, another website is [Scanwp](https://scanwp.net/) which is for Wordpress websites and detects themes and plugins used.

Comment: I know, I need to use it in my website, I want my visitors to check the same.